# Problem with SetSuspendState

Tags: c++, windows, windows-xp, standby

I write a small application to enter the computer to Standby Mode:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <PowrProf.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   SetSuspendState(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE);

   return 0;
}
```

I get this error:
1>Standby.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SetSuspendState@12
1>C:\Documents and Settings\Sobak\Desktop\Standby\Release\Standby.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externalsexternals

How can I fix it?

P.S.
I use Visual Studio 2005

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should link your programm with the `PowrProf.lib` library. You could do it by adding the following string:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "PowrProf.lib")
```